# how can I find that my net is enable or not without doing anything in my app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am using my app and Internet connection is disable. Next, I am going to enable my Internet connection. Now how can I find that my Internet connection is enabled or not without doing anything in my app?

I am working in obj-c.

Comment: Using Rechability : https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check for an active Internet connection on iOS or OSX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-ios-or-osx)

Comment: @JimmyJames thanks, this link solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

import `Reachability.h` file from [here](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) and do like following:

```
if ([[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection]currentReachabilityStatus]==NotReachable)
    {
         //Do here what you want to do when connection unavailable
    }
    else
    {
         //Do here what you want to do when connection available
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method

```
+(BOOL)isNetAvailable
{
  CFNetDiagnosticRef dReference;
  dReference = CFNetDiagnosticCreateWithURL (NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.apple.com"]);

  CFNetDiagnosticStatus status;
  status = CFNetDiagnosticCopyNetworkStatusPassively (dReference, NULL);

  CFRelease (dReference);

  if ( status == kCFNetDiagnosticConnectionUp )
  {
      NSLog (@"Connection is Available");
      return YES;
  }
  else
  {
      NSLog (@"Connection is down");
      return NO;
  }
}
```